# Plot data from Poisson GLM in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, glm

I have some count data in two categories, and have carried out a poisson GLM to look for differences in the two categories:

`mod <- glm(count ~ category, family = "poisson")`

For a poster, I want a simple plot of the results - probably a bar chart with error bars. Is there an easy way to get the plot data from `mod`? Do the error bars correspond to the model `Std. Error`? For what it's worth, I plan to use `ggplot2` to make the figure.

Also, am I right in thinking that, for a Poisson GLM, the model units are the log of 'real' units - so if the `Estimate` for `categoryB` is, say, 0.4 then this corresponds to observations in Category B having, on average, exp(0.4) = 1.5 higher count than Category A?

Comment: have you tried plot(mod)? Usually something is already implemented there.. :) Hope it helps: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70558/diagnostic-plots-for-count-regression

Comment: `plot(mod)` just plots the diagnostic plots for the model, rather than the results.